# OpenSAML2 library DefaultBootstrap to be called only once?

Tags: java, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

Using OpenSAML to unmarshal a SAML assertion from a HTTP response. So using this dependency:

```
org.opensaml:opensaml:2.6.1
```

I am following the guide [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUsrManJavaCreateFromXML).

I need to call this method to bootstrap the library:

```
DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
```

It is unclear whether I only need to call this method once when the application / library is loaded OR if I need to call it each time I need to unmarshal a SAML assertion. I suspect the former but it is not clear from the example in the link above or the Javadoc.

Thoughts?

Comment: Commenting on my own post! This code sample suggests it only needs to be done once: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=carbon-commons-master/components/hostobjects/org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects.sso/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/hostobjects/sso/internal/util/Util.java

Comment: Usually is once. But in some cases you will have more than one classloder, and in this case you will need initilize it more times (one per classloader). If you are getting Strange NoClassDefFound exception may be becouse this cenario.